# How to display SQL Server Table values in Comma Separated Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table - tabtest

Col1 Col2 Col3
abc  NULL xyz
NULL NULL mno
NULL pqr  stuv
def  lmn  NULL
```

How to display comma separated values like

```
OUTPUTX
abc,xyz
mno
pqr,stuv
def,lmn
```

Below is my query, which displays correct, however if cell value contains comma, it gives wrong

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(col1)),' ')+',' + ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(col2)),' ')+ ','+ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(col3)),' '),',,',','),' ,',''),', ','') outputx from [tabtest]
```

Please help

Comment: You could just do a bunch of `ISNULL` statements... e.g. `SELECT ISNULL(col1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(col2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(col3, '') [ConcatCols] FROM tblName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo Here](http://rextester.com/KXWY7250)</kbd>

This works with N columns:

```
;With cte
as
(select 
*,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn from t1
)
select stuff(b.t,1,1,'')  from cte
cross apply
(select ','+v
from
(values(col1),(col2),(col3)) b(v)
for xml path(''))b(t)
```

--This is specifically for three columns

```
 ;With cte
    as
    (
        select 
        col1+',' as col1,
        case when col3 is null or col2 is null 
             then col2 else col2+',' 
        end as col2,
        col3 as col3
        from t1
    )
    Select CONCAT(col1,col2,col3) from cte
```

When there are no nulls,you can simply do like

```
 select CONCAT(col1,','col2,',',col3) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1
`SELECT ISNULL(col1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(col2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(col3, '')`

Solution 2
[look here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2346/different-options-for-query-results-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

and [change this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKEev.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
`select 
 case
 when col1 is not null and col2 is null and col3 is null then col1
 when col1 is null and col2 is not null and col3 is null then col2
 when col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is not null then col3
 when col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is null then col1+','+col2
 when col1 is not null and col2 is null and col3 is not null then col1+','+col3
 when col1 is null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null then col2+','+col3
 when col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null then col1+','+col2+','+col3 
 else cast(null as varchar(50)) end OUTPUTX
 from tabtest2
```

`